# Testing whether a component is in the correct DOM with mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

currently I am creating a custom web component and I want to use mocha as my testing framework. Is there a way to check whether the component that I created is inserted into the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha is mostly just a framework to describe your tests and assert things. For checking whether a component you created is in the DOM, you can probably use plain old JavaScript with [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [document.get​Element​ById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). But yes, you would use that together with Mocha to write your test.